# MySQL and Laravel - checking existing record before and after

Tags: mysql, laravel

What's the simplest way to check if the record before which I am looking exists? For example when i search record with ID=2 there is previous record with ID=1, but when i search record ID=1 there isn't record before (same as searching last record ID, there isn't next record).

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why not determine which ID is the one "before" the current ID?

Comment: Before and after would depend on how you are sorting the results. Maybe add a timestamp to each record on create.

Comment: Please show some code, including what you expect and what you get. This question is a bit abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE 
`id` = (select `id` from table WHERE `id` > 0 and `id` < 2 ORDER by `id` desc limit 1) or 
`id` = 2 or 
`id` = (select `id` from table where `id` > 2 and `id` < (select `id` from table ORDER by `id` desc limit 1) limit 1)
```

"2" will be passing from code and query gives me 3 records with IDs 1,2,3 as i wanted, now i just need to "convert" it to right laravel eloquent version